Как можно модифицировать готовый apk файл
Здравствуйте подскажите кто знает как можно это убрать уже из готового апк файла при загрузке приложения через 2-3 секунды появляется этот логотип и при нажатие на него перекидывает на их сайт
Хочу это убрать из приложения уже дикомрелировал апк файл но найти этот изображения и код не как не могу

Уже декомпилировал апк файл но не могу найти где вшит этот логотип и код для запуска его При нажатие на него перекидывает на сайт

пишут, что раньше был апк, который позволял удалять, но сейчас он не работает https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/17d855v/am_i_the_only_one_whos_overly_annoyed_by_this/ //а вы смотрели в res/drawable  возможно, оно будет называться чем-то вроде logo.png, splash.png или похожим именем ?

Смотрел искал не как не могу найти как я понял не один уже искал эту информацию

Просто они это вшили так что фиг это найдешь все фалый просмотрел в раскрытом апк файле и не чего не нашел

Не думали, что изображение может быть закодировано в массив байтов?

А как найти этот массив байтов ?
И возможно ли в массив байтов подключить ссылку потому что при нажатие на этот логотип открывается сайт

Это же не веб из прошлого века, когда не было скриптов, только голый html. Картинка может быть вообще никак не связана с переходом в браузер - это делает обработчик события, прикреплённый к области экрана. С такой проблемой лучше идти на 4пда.
